# Problem during deployment to Wildfly, with error "name is empty"

Tags: jboss, migration, wildfly

we are migrating from Jboss 4.2.2 to Wildfly. During deployment we are facing the following error.
Googling the error diidn't find anything. The error doesn't provide useful details.
my-server.jar defines several ejb3 beans.
Does anybody has an idea what might be wrong?

```
    16:51:55,788 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."myapp.ear"."my-server.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."myapp.ear"."my-server.jar".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "my-server.jar" of deployment "myapp.ear"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name is empty
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:391)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ResourceReferenceProcessor.getResourceRefEntries(ResourceReferenceProcessor.java:157)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ResourceReferenceProcessor.processDescriptorEntries(ResourceReferenceProcessor.java:74)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.AbstractDeploymentDescriptorBindingsProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentDescriptorBindingsProcessor.java:100)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
        ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete every file and folder in wildfly --> standalone --> deployments and then run the standalone.bat file in wildfly --> bin.

Also, what made it work for us was to include the following dependency in the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunatelly, in our case it didn't solve the issue.
Also unfortunatelly, our project is pretty old and don't use maven, we use ant.